# How to override CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, overriding

I inspected it with Google Chrome and found this :

```
<div class="_2p3a" style="min-width: 180px; width: 270px;">
```

It should be :

```
<div class="_2p3a" style="min-width: 160px; width: 188px;">
```

But how to change it? It's a css from facebook. I tried to override it like that:

Added this line in my style.css, it doesn't work :

```
._2p3a {
min-width: 160px !important; 
width: 188px !important;
}
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: The Facebook widget is loaded in an `iframe` so you can not override the styles.

Comment: there is no such class in your own css, after close inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This widget shown inside iframe. We can't modify any styles or scripts inside the iframe.

Try to get correct size widget in facebook developer account.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the facebook link in the iframe, you will see that the current dimensions of this plugin are : `width:270px` and `height:330px`.

[image]

You will have to change thoses dimensions if you want the iframe to fit in your side div.

Try changing the values in the URL : [Your facebook plugin](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/pages/Ville-de-Torcy/1446855015630359?ref=hl&width=270&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color=white&stream=false&header=false&height=330)

Answer (score 1):

plz set your plugin width(iframe width)
from ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) Facebook